# If we have a connected graph that remains connected after removing any edge, can we make the following claim

Tags: graph-theory

Given we have a connected graph $G$ that remains connected if any edge in $G$ is removed

Say we have $(a, b) \in E(G)$ (where $E(G)$ is the set of all edges in $G$) and $(c, d) \in E(G)$.

Can we assume that $(a, d) \in E(G)$? I would assume no because the graph can be still be connected if an edge from $(a, d)$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any cycle graph serves as a counterexample to your claim.

Take for instance a cycle with four nodes in the order $a$, $b$, $d$, $c$. It contains edges $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, but not $(a,d)$. So you are correct that the assumption does not hold.

Comment: So my assumption is incorrect and the claim that $(a, d) \in E(G)$ is correct?

Comment: @Kermitty Updated my answer